# What to do with not-a-question questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

While doing a review, I saw this "first question" [Creating simple citygml 3D models based on 2D shapefiles (alkis) shp2gml using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230994/creating-simple-citygml-3d-models-based-on-2d-shapefiles-alkis-shp2gml-using-p). To my surprise, the OP posted a first question with the sole purpose of sharing a (lengthy) solution he/she found after some research.

What's the appropriate action for this kind of questions?

I left a comment suggesting to post the solution as a self-answer. But I just wanted to check with the meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you.

- Solutions should be posted within answers.
- Questions should be reserved for posing problems as questions
- [Self-answering is fine and encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

As someone coming across this question via your Meta question, rather than via the Review Queue, the action I took and would suggest is appropriate in either case, was to make a comment (like you did) but also to apply a downvote to draw the asker's attention to the high desirability of correcting the "Q&A format breakage" (and not rewarding it).  In such cases I would only downvote if there was a net positive score because downvoting well written content to a negative score is likely to attract an immediate sympathy upvote which undoes the desired message.  Once the Q&A was largely fixed I withdrew my downvote.

An alternative of voting to close as "unclear what you are asking" would not work because it would prevent them self-answering (the very action that we want them to learn to take).

Answer (score 4):

Self-answering is quite acceptable here, and encouraged.  There is even an option to *Answer your own question* while posting a Question

[image]

An answer should not be given in the body of the question, rather it should be formatted as a question and then the solution given in an answer.